# JavaFX WebView not executing Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, javafx, dropbox-api

I am trying to use the Dropbox Api in a project and am therefore implementing the OAuth 2.0 flow. I implemented the entire flow using a JavaFX WebView, but I am experiencing the following issue:

1. The auth flow is initiated, a window with a JavaFX WebView pops up and navigates to the dropbox auth page.
2. The user enters his account info and hits the sign in button
3. A little progress indicator appears next to the sign in button and keeps spinning forever.

The auth url is the following:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<your-client-id>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=<redirect-url>
```

What I found out so far:

- I opened the auth url in my browser and inspected the login button there. It turns out that the login is handled through an ajax-request (`<form action="/ajax_login" ... method="POST" ...>`)
- The WebView does not load a new page (I have a progress bar that shows up when a new page is loaded)

I therefore think that the web view simply doesn't execute the ajax call.

Here's the MCVE (you need to [register your own dropbox app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create) for it to work):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXWebViewAjaxIssue extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        String clientId = ""; // Put your client id in
        String redirectURL = ""; // put your redirect url in

        String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=" + clientId + "&response_type=token&redirect_uri=" + redirectURL;

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(url);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not directly a solution, but it might help others in the future. It turns out, that the JavaFx WebView seems to be lagging behind in terms of features ([source](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013137-jxbrowser-vs-javafx-webview)) and official support has been dropped ([source](https://www.java-forum.org/thema/webview-alternative.173043/)). I therefore switched to [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser).

JxBrowser is paid by default, but they grant free licenses to open source projects. Due to licensing and other reasons, JxBrowser is not as easy to use as the WebView, but since it uses Chromium, it is up to date in terms of features and soes not seem to have bugs like this one.

Btw, I am NOT affiliated with TeamDev or JxBrowser in any way, I am just using it in a project of mine :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that there is no such thing as a free licence for open source project, only a free trial... They might have changed that a few years ago. :-(